# How to show multiple sections one after other in angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have 3 sections/div, I want to show one after other. For example once I click 'show progress' button , first of all 'first' div should show only,after few second 'second' div should show hiding 'first' one, then after few second 'first and 'second' div should hide and third should show. Its working fine for first time , but when I click again its not working. Is there any better way I can do it. Here is the code   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atf7ja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="showdivs()">show progress</button>

<div *ngIf="first">First div</div>
<div *ngIf="second">Second div</div>
<div *ngIf="third">Third div</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  first: boolean = false;
  second: boolean = false;
  third: boolean = false;
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit() {}
  showdivs() {
    this.first = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.first = false;
      this.second = true;
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.first = false;
      this.second = false;
      this.third = true;
    }, 8000);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qctpih?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts take this for reference too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: Instead of using multiple boolean variables (first, second, third), just use one single variable like "status".

```ts
export class AppComponent {
   status: 'none' | 'first' | 'second' | 'third' = 'none';

   showdivs() {
    this.status = 'first';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = 'second';
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = 'third';
    }, 8000);
  }
}
```

In your html:

```html
<div *ngIf="status === 'first'">First div</div>
<div *ngIf="status === 'second'">Second div</div>
<div *ngIf="status === 'third'">Third div</div>
```

This structure avoids cases like accidentally having "first" and "second" displayed at the same time. Also, it is more scalable: You could create hundreds of steps by only using one single variable.

To make this even more type safe, you could use an enum like so:

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  status: Status = Status.None;

  // This is used to make the enum available in the template.
  readonly STATUS_ENUM = Status;  

   showdivs() {
    this.status = Status.First;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = Status.Second;
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.status = Status.Third;
    }, 8000);
  }
}

enum Status {
  None,
  First,
  Second,
  Third
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="status === STATUS_ENUM.First">First div</div>
<div *ngIf="status === STATUS_ENUM.Second">Second div</div>
<div *ngIf="status === STATUS_ENUM.Third">Third div</div>
```

Comment: It is also my idea to use only one variable. But why stop here? There's much more to do. Stop using human numbers (one, two three, four...) What if there are one-hundred-and-seventy-six slides?? Will you enumerate them all? Just use numerals 1, 2, 3, 4. Huge simplification, and you can do `slide++` and `slide--`. Then, instead of `*ngIf *ngIf *ngIf *ngIf`, use one `*ngSwitch`.

Comment: The idea with `*ngSwitch` is definitely making the code even better structured - I like that!

Regarding the numerals: This highly depends on your use case. The big disadvantage over using an enum is that, if at some point in time you want to insert something in the "middle" of your slides, you have to update all of the `*ngSwitchCase` fields coming after it. So it could make sense to even introduce a mapping `(slide-number) <--> (enum-entry)`. But I guess we are overcomplicating things here :D

Answer (score 0):

You forget

```
this.third = false;
```

in the first setTimeout

BTW, I like use [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) rxjs/operators, so you can write

```
import {timer} from 'rxjs'
import {take} from 'rxjs/operators'

  showDivs(){
    timer(0,4000).pipe(
      take(3)).subscribe(res=>{
        this.first=res==0
        this.second=res==1
        this.third=res==2
      })
  }
```

**Update** another aproach, as all users say you you can has a variable and show only if the variable is equal to 0, 1 or 2. So I improve my answer using pipeasync and this "tecnica". If you has

```
showDivs(){
  this.timer$=timer(0,400).pipe(
   take(3))
}
```

You can has

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{data:timer$|async} as tm">
  <div *ngIf="tm.data==0">First div</div>
  <div *ngIf="tm.data==1">Second div</div>
  <div *ngIf="tm.data==2">Third div</div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @MBuchalik, I think that obviously you have to use one variable for all, instead of one variable per slide. You can't just enumerate in human language all your slides one by one.

Imagine there are one-hundred-and-seventy-six slides; will you write one-hundred-and-seventy-six times the same instructions set, in every one of which you enumerate all one-hundred-and-seventy-six slides one by one, hiding or showing the one you want?? That's thirty thousand nine hundred and seventy six lines of code :)

No, the solution is 1) to use one variable for all and 2) to use numerals, not English numbers.

Also, instead of `*ngIf *ngIf *ngIf *ngIf`, use one `*ngSwitch`. Something like that :

```
<div [ngSwitch]="slideNumber">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="1">First div</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="2">Second div</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="3">Third div</div> 
</div>
```

Component :

```
public slideNumber:number = 1;

slideNumber++; // Next slide
slideNumber--; // Previous slide
slideNumber = 8; // Jump to one particular slide
```

Job done.